BlobClient#generateSasUrl automatically %-encode blob path
const { BlockBlobClient, BlobSASPermissions } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(
  "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yyyy;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "test",
  "hoge/huga/baz.txt"
);

const expiresOn = new Date();
expiresOn.setMinutes(expiresOn.getMinutes() + 5);
const h = blobClient.generateSasUrl({ expiresOn, permissions: BlobSASPermissions.from({ read: true })}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

Executing this script, which uses Azure JavaScript SDK, outputs
https://yyyy.blob.core.windows.net/test/hoge%2Fhuga%2Fbaz.txt?sv=2024-05-04&se=2024-07-09T03%3A38%3A03Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=wHPR6FOUyvXWdQafJ%2F8deC1lVH%2Fl0%2Fu4ZGqqLcsJDmU%3D.
Is this expected behavior? How can I make path to be /test/hoge/huga/baz.txt?


Is this expected behavior? How can I make path to be /test/hoge/huga/baz.txt?

Yes, it is expected behavior, you can change the expected(decoded) path using below code.
Code:
const { BlockBlobClient, BlobSASPermissions } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(
  "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat891;AccountKey=r4kv43+pifLxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "sample",
  "data/store/001.csv"
);

const expiresOn = new Date();
expiresOn.setMinutes(expiresOn.getMinutes() + 5);

blobClient.generateSasUrl({ expiresOn, permissions: BlobSASPermissions.from({ read: true })})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('Encoded URL:', res);

    const url = new URL(res);
    const encodedPath = url.pathname;
    const decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(encodedPath);
    const decodedUrl = url.origin + decodedPath + url.search;

    console.log('Decoded URL:', decodedUrl);
  });

Output:
PS C:\Users\xxxvexxkat\xxx> node example.js
Encoded URL: https://venkat891.blob.core.windows.net/sample/data%2Fstore%2F001.csv?sv=2024-05-04&se=2024-07-09T04%3A15%3A24Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=zBG%2Bxe90xxxxxxxx
Decoded URL: https://venkat891.blob.core.windows.net/sample/data/store/001.csv?sv=2024-05-04&se=2024-07-09T04%3A15%3A24Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=zBGxxxxx


I also checked the blob URL is working fine.


My colleague investigated further on this.
Rationale beind this design is explained in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/6886#issuecomment-572852591.
According to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/pull/23461,
a fix is to use ContainerClient#getBlobClient.
const client = new ContainerClient(
  "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yyyy;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "test"
).getBlobClient("hoge/huga/baz.txt");

const expiresOn = new Date();
expiresOn.setMinutes(expiresOn.getMinutes() + 5);

client
  .generateSasUrl({
    expiresOn,
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.from({ read: true }),
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });

